# Why am I getting 404 with Go in docker

Tags: docker, go, routes

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build
RUN apk --no-cache add gcc g++ make git
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go get ./...
RUN GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o ./bin/web-app ./main.go

FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /usr/bin
COPY --from=build /go/src/app/bin /go/bin
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/web-app --port 80
```

And this is a simple main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public")))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}
```

The public directory is in the same folder with the main.go file. There is an index.html in the public directory.
When I run `go run main.go` my website is served properly. But with Docker, I get the 404 page. I suspect it has to do with the placement of the files inside the docker container. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create the folder in your `alpine` container:

```
RUN mkdir -p /go/bin/public
```

and make sure to have something in that folder.

or you need to copy the folder and files from the first go container.

and edit your dokcerfile :

```
WORKDIR /go/bin
ENTRYPOINT web-app --port 80
```

Comment: ```ENTRYPOINT ./web-app --port 80``` worked. With the public folder at the same level.

Answer (score 1):

As LinPy has mentioned you should copy the public folder from build to alpine

And you have to set the WORKDIR to /go in order for the relative path to work

eg.

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build
RUN apk --no-cache add gcc g++ make git
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go get ./...
RUN GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o ./bin/web-app ./main.go

FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /go
COPY --from=build /go/src/app/bin /go/bin
COPY --from=build /go/src/app/public /go/public
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/web-app --port 80
```